# Checkbox filter in ng-table?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, ngtable

I would like to achieve similar to the screenshot below in ng-table of Angular JS

[image: Checkbox filter in table]
Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What effort have you made to solve the problem?

Comment: I need a starting point to this
Later I can write by myself

Comment: @NishPatwa Implementing this involves a lot of things. We dont know how you are bringing the data, how you are writing the html, what libraries, frameworks you are using, which technologies are involved... Until and unless you try something and provide the code you written we cant help you.

Comment: you need to provide exact requirements and the code you have written so far. Image is too vague to understand.